# Find First Iteration of Map in React/Javascript

Tags: javascript, arrays, reactjs

I'm mapping an object array in React and I want to find the first iteration of `chosenFields` array.

People Array:

```
[ { id:1, name:"Jim", occupation:"Programmer".........} 
  {id:2, name:"Sally", occupation:"Pet Sitter".......}]
```

I have another object array that is in charge of what fields are suppose to be displayed from the PeopleArray:

chosenFields Array:

```
[{label:"id", show:true}, {label:"name", show:true}, {label:"occupation", show:false}]
```

I want to know if there's a way that the code can recognize when it first iterates through `chosenFields` Array for each row of the `People` Array

```
    renderSingleData(rowListData, currData){ 
      //find which one is the first iteration to add a radiobox for each row
   }

    renderUserData(currRow){
        return(
            <div>
                {chosenFields.map(this.renderChosenData.bind(this, currRow)}            
            </div>
        )
    }

  render() {
    return (
        <div >
            {PeopleData.map(this.renderUserData.bind(this))}
        </div>
    );
  }
}
```

This is a very simplified version of the code. I need to add an iteration to a table via `<td>`. I'm currently using a variable in React and setting the state with a counter. I'm wondering if there's a more straightforward way to find iterations via the map function.

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at the [docs](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map?v=example) for `Array.prototype.map()`

The callback function's second argument is the index. If this is 0, then that is the first iteration of the callback. In your case, you may need to propagate that condition up a few callbacks. Something like...

```
renderSingleData(isFirst, rowListData, currData){ 
    //find which one is the first iteration to add a radiobox for each row
}

renderUserData(currRow, currIdx){
    return(
        <div>
            {chosenFields.map(this.renderChosenData.bind(this, currIdx === 0, currRow)}            
        </div>
    )
}

render() {
    return (
        <div >
            {PeopleData.map(this.renderUserData.bind(this))}
        </div>
    );
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the response! I tried something like this initially but I'm getting an error: ReferenceError: currIdx is not defined

Comment: @lost9123193 is `PeopleData` an Array?

Comment: yep it's an object array

Comment: @lost9123193, that's strange. Is the method being called from anywhere else?